# Django model aggregate matches count in ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-aggregation

There is Model with ManyToMany field:

```
class Number(Model):
    current_number = IntegerField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    numbers_set = models.ManyToMany(Number)
```

For example we have such dataset:

```
my_model_1.numbers_set = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_model_2.numbers_set = [2, 3, 4, 5]
my_model_3.numbers_set = [3, 4, 5, 6]
my_model_4.numbers_set = [4, 5, 6, 7]
my_model_5.numbers_set = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I'm looking for a way to aggregate MyModel by amount of same numbers.

f.e. MyModel objects that have at least 3 same numbers in theirs numbers_set.

```
[
    [my_model_1, my_model_2],
    [my_model_2, my_model_3],
    [my_model_3, my_model_4, my_model_5],
]
```

Comment: What if more than two models have at least 3 same numbers? Do you want all of them in the same list?

Comment: @AKS, Yes.  (I've added your question to example)

Comment: Which database and Django version are you using?

Comment: @AKS, Django=1.9.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111597/discussion-between-alex-t-and-aks).

Comment: Note: Since you're using Postgres, you may be able to just use an [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

Comment: @Sayse, thanks. But it's just very general example, of course in my case it's not just int values.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Postgres  version 9.4 and Django version 1.9 , It's better to use `JSONField()` rather than using `ManyToMany()`, for indexing purpose use `jsonb` indexing on Postgres which will provide you efficient query for fetching data. Check [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: In real case instead of Number I have quite common model with various fields (TextField, CharField, DateTimeField, IntegerField). So I assume I can't use JSONField..